# How to group all custom modules under one menu using hook_menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I just started learning drupal 7 module development. I wanted to group all my custom modules under one category (say custom). I know how to **manually** do that using **"admin/structure/menu/manage/management"**. But is it possible to create a new group and put all my module menus under that group using hook_menu ?

**For Example :**

```
  function hook_menu() {
  $items['admin/settings/custom/module-name'] = array(
  //other code here
  ); 
}
```

The above code doesn't create the "custom" menu item instead it creates "module-name" menu. I want to put "module-name" under "custom" ?

Comment: you should create `$items['admin/settings/custom']` menu too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [kalabro](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2466/kalabro) for the answer. For those who are new to module development and need the same functionality, I've posted the code below :

```
  function hook_menu() {
  $items['admin/settings/custom'] = array();
  $items['admin/settings/custom/module-name'] = array(
  //other code here
  ); 
}
```

You can use the **"$items['admin/settings/custom'] = array();"** in a separate module also.

**Note :** 
Be sure to flush the cache. Sometimes you might need to disable and then enable the modules again for this to work...

Comment: Where should I write this code ? In which module ?

Comment: it's required (highly suggestable) not only to disable/enable but also uninstall/install

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Sharan didn't work with the current Drupal 7.34. An empty array will not create a new group,
 even after disabling and uninstalling and re-enabling the module and flushing caches and so on...

I did some research and found a way that works quite well. It will create an new item (with subitems) in the **'Management' menu**, that
has it's own (translatable) title and description. When the group itself is opened in a browser (**'admin/config/custom'** in the example),
it will show an **overview page** that lists all the subitems with descriptions. It also integrates as expected with the menu bar from the **admin_menu module**.

```php
function hook_menu() {
  // The new group
  $items['admin/config/custom'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom settings',
    'description' => 'All the custom settings.',
    // 'position' and 'weight' can be used to place
    // the group in the the parent overview (admin/config).
    'position' => 'right',
    'weight' => -20,
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    // This renders the group overview.
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    // 'file' and 'file path' are required for the
    // 'system_admin_menu_block_page' callback.
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc', 
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module','system'),
  );
  // A subitem in the group
  $items['admin/config/custom/module-name'] = array(
    //other code here
  ); 
}
```

**EDIT:** A cache flush should be enough to enable the group.

Comment: Where should I write this code ? In which module ?